# How to get maximum column condensed in one row with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

For the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 0, 11], "b": [7, 0, 0], "c": [0,10,0], "d": [1,0,0],
                   "e": [0,0,0], "name":["b","c","a"]})

print(df)
    a  b   c  d  e name
0   1  7   0  1  0    b
1   0  0  10  0  0    c
2  11  0   0  0  0    a
```

I would like to get one row back that comprises the maximum values of each column plus the name of that column.

E.g. in this case:

```
a  b  c d e name
11 7 10 1 0    a
```

How can this be performed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get maximum values to one row DataFrame by [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transposse by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and then get `name` of maximum value per DataFrame with [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
a = df.max().to_frame().T
a.loc[0, 'name'] = df.set_index('name').max(axis=1).idxmax()

print (a)
    a  b   c  d  e name
0  11  7  10  1  0    a
```

Detail:

```
print (df.set_index('name').max(axis=1))
name
b     7
c    10
a    11
dtype: int64

print (df.set_index('name').max(axis=1).idxmax())
a
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`df.max()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) and create a [`Dataframe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)and [`Transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) as:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.max()).T

    a  b   c  d  e name
0  11  7  10  1  0    c
```